# Test-NetConnection works from Windows Server 2016 A to B but not B to A

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2016

I've got a puzzler.   I have to systems running Windows Server 2016 (actually two EC2 instances from the same AMI).

A: #.#.#.10 controller.me.env
B: #.#.#.20 client.me.env

- WORKS - on A `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName A`
- WORKS - on A `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName B`
- **FAILS** - on B `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName A`
- WORKS - on B `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName B`

I can use the DNS name or the ip address and I get the same pattern of fails and passes.  Both instances are:

- in the same **availability zone**
- share the same **security group**
- use the same userdata which enables ansible

I'm baffled.  Anyone got any clues?

Comment: ICMP open on the firewall on B?

Comment: what about the inbound firewall rule (for ICMP traffic) in the WS 2016 B? is that configured properly?

Comment: Agreed with the other two comments. If you've shared a file or folder on server B these rules will have been automatically created and enabled.

Comment: Have  you tried specifying the port to see if it's the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong.

First of all, neither direction worked.
Secondly, my security group blocked ICMP traffic and Test-NetConnection uses ICMP
protocol.
Thirdly (and this was the real problem):

I was trying to get HLK to work between client / controller and it failed.  This was because the two Windows Server 2016 systems were not setup to append my domain to the hostname for lookups.

When I modified the connection and added my domain as default for DNS (and probably WINS) lookups connectivity in the test and for the actual goal worked.

Thanks for the help.